# How do I determine what is different between two different xlsx versions of the same worksheet?

Tags: excel, reportviewer, xlsx, testcomplete

I apologize in advance if my question seems somewhat vague (if only I could attach a file that would be so much better!)

I use TestComplete for regression testing, part of which is .rdl-type reports in our software being exported in the .xls format and compared to a previously saved copy.

A newer version of the software will export the file in the .xlsx format, and pretesting this in TestComplete is causing the following issue:  The .xlsx file opens just fine using Microsoft Excel, but the following in TestComplete fails to open it:

DDT.ExcelDriver(strSourceSpreadsheet, strSheet, True)

However, if I open the file with Microsoft Excel and re-save it (making no changes), then the above line of code works just fine.

So the next thing I did was to change the .xlsx extension on the before Excel and after Excel versions to .zip, and then tried comparing the two collections of files.

The re-saved version is almost twice as big as the original one, has additional files, and all the common files are full of differences.  How to I even begin trying to get to the bottom of this?  Has anyone experienced something similar?

Thanks,

PKK

UPDATE:  Of two different reporting formats, the one can be read just fine by the call to DDT.ExcelDriver(...) in TestComplete.  It seems that the problem only comes up with .xlsx files created by MS Report Viewer: 12.0, I think.

Comment: It may very well be that the initially saved .XLSX is missing something that TestComplete expects to be there. Some software is more forgiving than others in that regard. Saving the file from Excel as a "Strict XML spreadsheet" may give you a clue what

Comment: I tried saving it in the Strict Open XML Format, and as far as I can tell (using Microsoft Office Spreadsheet Compare)  that produced the exact same results as saving it in the Excel Workbook file

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before. If the excel file is getting larger just due to saving, you may have a rogue "last cell" which causes Excel to think the file is larger. Basically saving a bunch of blank cells. The steps to resolve are here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/why-do-my-excel-files-become-huge/8235dc08-aa70-4a65-9892-b776790d79c5?auth=1

Comment: If I open the two files in excel and hit CTRL-End, both versions end at Y25.  And if I save the xlsx files as zip files and then examine the actual sheet1.xml files, the newer version is only 5% bigger, so the size increase is coming from just about everywhere BUT the worksheet???